# Rename [csrf] → [cross-site-request-forgery]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I would like to propose renaming the [csrf](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csrf) tag to [cross-site-request-forgery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-site-request-forgery).

> a cross site request forgery attack causes a visitor of a malicious website to send a request to a legit website to which he is already logged in including the session cookie.

The tag was originally abbreviated to fit within the 25 character limit. Now that the maximum tag length has been [increased to 35](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/299490/351462), I don't see any reason not to use the full name, while keeping the abbreviated name as a tag synonym.

Comment: I'd be tempted to have csrf as the master, and add cross-site-request-forgery as a tag synonym, as csrf is the commonly used name.

Comment: Absolutely agree @RoryAlsop.

Answer (score 11):

I agree with @RoryAlsop here. Let's keep the main tag [csrf](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csrf) and let  [cross-site-request-forgery](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cross-site-request-forgery) be a synonym, just in case.

Just as with SQL, which is rarely ever called "Structured Query Language", we should stick to the usage that's most common. XSS and CSRF are well-established acronyms that keep the tag list concise.

Comment: +1 both for keeping [csrf], and for adding a synonym.